# WHERE clause and INT(11) data type is not working in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, unique-key

In my `user` table I have column called `SeedNumber` which is declared as `INT(11)`. In MySQL database `INT` is always represented by 4 bytes, and the number 11 in parenthesis does not mean that INT value will be restricted on the 11 digits. [This blog](http://everythingmysql.ning.com/profiles/blogs/data-type-confusion-what-is-an) explains it well.

Here is MySQL declaration for the field `SeedNumber`:

[image]

By using field `SeedNmb`, I want to fetch user. The following SQL query is used:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE SeedNmb=99999617
```

In my table, the value 99999617 is current maximum value. This query returns me a user without any problems, like it is demonstrated on the image below:

[image]

Recently a new user registered with SeedNumber equal 12561361. When I search the new user using the email column in the query, I get the following result:

```
select * from user where email like ("dennis@ca....bin.com");
```

Here is result:

[image: Result when searching by email]

But when I search for a user with a query:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE SeedNmb=12561361
```

I do not get any result, and that is a problem. The image below demonstrates my problem:

[image: No result when searching by SeedNumber]

It seems like a where clause is somehow not working and user is not returned as result.

Value 12 561 361 is not greater than 99 999 617 which is current maximum value in the `SeedNumber` table.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: May be this is panel bug? Can you try your query for example in `phpmyadmin` ?

Comment: I do not get a user when executing the query even using PHP. That was the reason why I executed the same query in the mysql workbench.

Comment: I connected to the DB using SSH. I tried to execute the same query, and I get "Empty set" result, so this eliminates the possibility that MySQL Workbench causes the issue.

Comment: Very strange. Is `12561361` the only SeedNmb that doesn't work?

Comment: No, there are more users. For example, SeedNmb 68979714 is not working too!

Comment: What happens when you query using `>` or `<` e.g. `SELECT * FROM user WHERE SeedNmb >= 10000000`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried putting the number between quotes?

```
 SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `SeedNmb` = '12561361';
```

Comment: I did but still the same result :(

Comment: That is weird. have you tried it with grave accents around the table name and column name? (grave accents is the sign next to your 1 on the left side) because user is also an action in MYSQL. So when you dont use the grave accents it will think it is the predefined action in MYSQL.[link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent)

Comment: What @Dennise89 said try using \``SeedNmb\`` in your query

Comment: Hm, unfortunatelly it didn't help. I added  `SeedNmb` but still get NULL as result

Comment: See updated answer :) make sure you use those backticks

Answer (score 0):

Try it in MySQL command line..
I guess something is wrong with your IDE.

Comment: I connected to the DB using SSH. I tried to execute the same query, and I get "Empty set" result, so this eliminates the possibility that MySQL Workbench causes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue and fixed it by recreating an index.  I noticed that if I used "like" instead of "=" the query would work.  The explain plan showed that an index was used only when using "=" and not when using "like" so I deleted and recreated that index.  The query started working again.